# Getter/setter "is used reflectively but not in MirrorsUsed" warning after dart2js compilation

Tags: dart, dart2js, dart-mirrors

In my class, I have getters and setters which are working thanks to NoSuchMethod - that is, they're not explicitly defined. After I compile and run the js, I get the following error in the browser console:

```
Warning: 'closes_in=' is used reflectively but not in MirrorsUsed. This will break minified code.
```

In this case, `closes_in=` is an example of such a setter and there are some other warnings related to other getters/setters too. I do have a `@MirrorsUsed` with the name of the library/class included and the resulting compiled js is actually smaller than it was without using `@MirrorsUsed` statements.

However, if a `-m` flag is passed to `dart2js`, then when the js program runs it fails - as predicted by the warning message.

Thus, I have two questions:
1. How do I write my `@MirrorsUsed` statement so that the warning goes away?
2. If it's not possible, how do I suppress the warning message? (because if it's not possible to solve the problem, then my only option would be to NOT minify the file then).

Comment: Good question. I never saw any documentation that helped me understand how it works. I guess you'll need to provide more code for anybody to provide support.